# How to store a Set in MongoDB with Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, list, set

The MongoDB Java client internally converts sets into lists when storing them. As a result, the elements have a specific ordering. When searching for a set you have inserted, you might miss it, when the set-to-list conversion leads to a different ordering. So how to store sets?

(One could convert the set to a list and sort it before searching/storing, but this is quite expensive.)

Example code:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("b");
set.add("a");
Document doc = new Document();
doc.put("set", set);
collection.insertOne(doc);
// next line would throw a ClassCastException
// set = ((Set<String>) doc.get("set")); 
set = new HashSet<String>((List<String>) doc.get("set"));

//searching for the set seems to work
doc = collection.find(Filters.eq("set", set)).first(); // <- not null
//but unfortunately, searching for 'set2' returns null, because it produces a different list as 'set'
Set<String> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<>();
set2.add("b");
set2.add("a");
doc = collection.find(Filters.eq("set", set2)).first(); // <- null
```

Comment: any update here?

Comment: unfortunately no, I decided to sort my values beforehand